# Aws Lambda to write to firebase storage

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, aws-lambda, firebase-storage

I want to write a downloaded file to Firebase **storage** using **AWS Lambda**.
I have already written a dynamic link for fire-storage

Can someone hint me how to do that? I have ready for s3 I want to store it in Firestorage now.

- Only the **index.html** to store in fire storage name **google-list/index.html**

````
    def lambda_handler(event, context):
        
        url='https://www.google.com/index.html' # put your url here
        bucket = 'google-list' #your s3 bucket
        key = 'index.html' #your path
        #write to s3 want to replace with firestorage.
        #s3=boto3.client('s3')
        #http=urllib3.PoolManager()
        #s3.upload_fileobj(http.request('GET', url,preload_content=False), bucket, key, ExtraArgs={'ACL':'public-read'})```
````

Comment: To get the help you need, you may reach out to https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact